# Python pandas: Append rows of DataFrame and delete the appended rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
    'text': ['abc','zxc','qwe','asf','efe','ert','poi','wer','eer','poy','wqr']})
```

I have a DataFrame with columns:

```
id    text
1      abc
2      zxc
3      qwe
4      asf
5      efe
6      ert
7      poi
8      wer
9      eer
10     poy
11     wqr
```

I have a list `L = [1,3,6,10]` which contains list of id's.

I am trying to append the text column using a list such that, from my list first taking 1 and 3(first two values in a list) and appending text column in my DataFrame with `id = 1` which has id's 2, then deleting rows with id column 2 similarly then taking 3 and 6 and then appending text column where `id = 4,5` to id 3 and then delete rows with id = 4 and 5 and iteratively for elements in list (x, x+1)

My final output would look like this:

```
id   text
1    abczxc         # joining id 1 and 2
3    qweasfefe      # joining id 3,4 and 5
6    ertpoiwereer   # joining id 6,7,8,9
10   poywqr         # joining id 10 and 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for Series, which is use for [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join` function:

```
s = df.id.where(df.id.isin(L)).ffill().astype(int)
df1 = df.groupby(s)['text'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
print (df1)
   id          text
0   1        abczxc
1   3     qweasfefe
2   6  ertpoiwereer
3  10        poywqr
```

It working because:

```
s = df.id.where(df.id.isin(L)).ffill().astype(int)
print (s)
0      1
1      1
2      3
3      3
4      3
5      6
6      6
7      6
8      6
9     10
10    10
Name: id, dtype: int32
```

Comment: sir your previous code `df.groupby(df.id.isin(L).cumsum())['text'].apply(''.join).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'text'})` was working fine, why did you introduced `.ffill().astype(int)` ? i mean what does it do?

Comment: It have different output in id column [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43454862/revisions), so I change it.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the values not in list to np.nan and then ffill and groupby. Though @Jezrael's approach is much better. I need to  remember to use cumsum:)

```
l = [1,3,6,10]
df.id[~df.id.isin(l)] = np.nan
df = df.ffill().groupby('id').sum()

        text
id  
1.0     abczxc
3.0     qweasfefe
6.0     ertpoiwereer
10.0    poywqr
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut` to create you bins then `groupby` with a lambda function to join your text in that group.

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.id,L+[np.inf],right=False, labels=[i for i in L])).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.text))
```

EDIT:

```
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df.id,L+[np.inf],
              right=False, 
              labels=[i for i in L]))
  .apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.text)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'text'}))
```

Output:

```
   id          text
0   1        abczxc
1   3     qweasfefe
2   6  ertpoiwereer
3  10        poywqr
```

Comment: at the end of your code i added .reset_index() to convert it into dataframe, but it gave me colum named as 0, instead of `text`